# APEI generic hardware error

Tags: kernel

The following error message is shown while installing ubuntu 13.10

```
[hardware error]: Hardware error from APEI generic hardware error source 0
[hardware error]: APEI generic hardware error status
[hardware error]: severity: 1, fatal
[hardware error]: section: 0, severity: 1, fatal
[hardware error]: flags: 0X01
[hardware error]: primary
[hardware error]: fru_text: uncorrectedErr
[hardware error]: section_type: PCIe error
[hardware error]: command: 0x0010, status: 0x0147
[hardware error]: device_id: 0000:00:00.0
[hardware error]: slot: 0
[hardware error]: secondary_bus: 0x00
[hardware error]: vendo_id: 0x1077, device_id: 0x7322
[hardware error]: class_code: 00060c
kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal hardware error!
rebooting in 30 seconds
```